# How to delete mapped children from associations table in sqlalchemy using relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

documentations says:

> Mapping a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship results in a collection of values accessible through an attribute on the parent instance. By default, this collection is a list

So I have user with roles and I can access it using user.roles and user.roles.append() method works fine, but I can't remove all mapped entries.
I tried:

```
 user.roles = []
```

also I tried clear() method and remove() in loop but I always get

```
    sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Can't flush None value found in collection Users.roles
```

this is example of my tables relationships

```
 class Users(sa.Model):
__tablename__ = 'users'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
login = Column(String(50), unique=False)

roles = relationship('Roles', secondary='user_roles_map',
                     cascade='all, delete')


class Roles(sa.Model):
__tablename__ = 'roles'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
name = Column(String(40), unique=True)



class UserRolesMap(sa.Model):
__tablename__ = 'user_roles_map'

id_seq = Sequence(__tablename__ + "_id_seq")
id = Column(Integer(), id_seq, server_default=id_seq.next_value(),
            unique=True, nullable=False)
user_id = Column(
    Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'),
    primary_key=True)
role_id = Column(
    Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id'),
    primary_key=True)
```

is it possible to remove all entries by accessing the roles attribute from the parent entry?

Comment: Check your code. I can reproduce your issue if I do `user.roles = [None]` but if I do `user.roles = []` [like this](https://pastebin.com/yMjUK09J) it works just fine.

Comment: @GordThompson
hm... it's strange I've tried to add flush() after roles changing and now it's working fine, before I had only commit() and I thought that commit calls flush underhood, and so says documentation :
"Session.commit() is used to commit the current transaction. It always issues Session.flush()"
but any way, thank you, now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call flush() was required after user.roles = []